# Why can't I log in with new/added e-mail address? (It's listed under "Other" on My Logins page)

Tags: support, bug, login, email-addresses

I updated my e-mail address at stats.stackexchange.com.  I verified it by clicking on the link in the e-mail I received.  My new e-mail address was added under "Other" on the My Logins page.
I can't log in with that e-mail.  No registered account associated with this e-mail address.

I want to use my new e-mail address to log in.  How, specifically, do I set that up?

Comment: Try doing it in Guest/Incognito mode of the browser.

Comment: "No user found with matching email"

Comment: I changed the password for that e-mail address under My Logins.  I still can't log in with that e-mail address.

Comment: Changing the password for the new e-mail address changed the login password for the old e-mail address.  So why does each address have it's own change password button, if there is only one overall password ?????????

Comment: Sorry, don't know. You can also submit a contact request (see "contact" in the footer of each page) with the details, and hopefully someone who does know will post answer here as well.